# Find Installed applications in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, macos

I am developing an application in cocoa.I need to check whether iTunes is installed or not in the machine.Is there any way to find the installed applications????

Answer (score 8):

The function LSFindApplicationForInfo() can take a bundle ID (e.g. `com.apple.iTunes`), so you can find out whether iTunes is installed by trying to look it up.

http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html

To answer the second part of your question, there *is* a hidden interface on LaunchServices to get a list of all application names. However, as your goal is to find whether iTunes is installed, don't use it - just look for iTunes.

Comment: Or one could even use -[NSWorkspace absolutePathForAppBundleWithIdentifier:] (which probably calls down to LSFindApplicationForInfo() anyway)

Comment: do you have more infos regarding the "hidden interface on LaunchServices to get a list of all application names" ?

Answer (score 6):

As was mentioned by Mike Abdullah the correct cocoa call is:

```
NSString* iTunesPath = [ [ NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace ] 
        absolutePathForAppBundleWithIdentifier: @"com.apple.iTunes" ];
if( iTunesPath ) {
    // iTunes installed, do something
}
```