# How to know what apps I install on one iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

If it possible to know what apps are installed on current device? And get some information, such as install date, size?

**EDIT**:
By programming.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to know this?

Answer (score 2):

All applications that are installed are on the home screen, you can swap between pages. The same thing can be done from iTunes, here you wil probobly find more information about your phone. If you can't find it in iTunes you wont find it anywhere else.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think the OP means programmatically. At least, I hope so, considering this is Stack Overflow.

Comment: Is it possible to know by programming?

Comment: Ofcourse you want it by code >_<!
Maybe this can help http://amitay.us/ihasapp/index.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on Mac OS X (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102256/find-installed-applications-in-cocoa) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003748/how-to-get-list-of-installed-appications-on-mac)), but not on iOS from what I can tell.

Just a note about the Launch Services solution as well, there's *probably* a private API call still around to let you do it, since on [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html) page Apple says the following:

> In iOS, Launch Services is a private API but is still used internally to coordinate the execution environment of iOS applications.

Something like this:

```
NSArray *urls;
_LSCopyAllApplicationURLs(&urls);
```

I'm not sure if that works on iOS. Even if it does, this will never get past App Store Compliance testing.